# VBA array can't increment size

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Working with access VBA and I can't seem to increment a 2d dynamic array. This seems like an easy task but I keep  "Subscript out of range" error @

> ReDim Preserve affected_CAN_sat(this_array_index,4)

My code:

```
Dim this_array() as Variant
ReDim this_array(0,4)

Dim this_array_index As integer
this_array_index = Ubound(this_array) 'index = 0

dim n as integer
For n = 0 to x ' x is unknown integer
this_array_index = this_array_index + 1
ReDim Preserve this_array(this_array_index,4)
Next
```

it SHOULD have incremented the array size but it hasn't. Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx#Anchor_2) on `ReDim`

> - **Resizing with Preserve.** If you use **Preserve**, you can resize only the last dimension of the array. For every other dimension, you must specify the bound of the existing array.

---

That being said, the logic of your code makes no sense - if you know the number that you loop is going to increment to and the upper boundary of the array is going to increase by one each time, then just initialize the array with the correct upper boundary instead of looping:

instead of:

```
For n = 0 to 10 '// <~~ We know this will only go up to 10
    this_array_index = this_array_index + 1
    ReDim Preserve affected_CAN_sat(this_array_index,4)
Next
```

If you know you're only going to loop to 10 then just do:

```
Dim affected_CAN_sat() As Variant
...
this_array_index = this_array_index + 10
ReDim Preserve affected_CAN_sat(0 To this_array_index, 0 To 4) As Variant
...
```

No need to loop.

Comment: Sorry, I used 10 as an example. The real case would've been an unknown number up to 4000.

Comment: You must know this number though at this point of the code in order to use the `For/Each` loop?

Comment: I'm aware but for the sake of getting to the main question, I chose to give little regard to it. However going back to your point prior, makes sense why ReDim doesn't work. Are there any possible solution to ReDim ONLY the size of array?

Comment: Not if you want to use `Preserve` as well. The point I was making (poorly) was about design - you need to re-think the logic of your code so that a loop isn't required to increment the upper boundary of the array. If it seems too big a task to re-design at this stage then perhaps use another object like an [ArrayList](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=167349) or a dictionary.